# Vertical align block level element inside a block level element

Tags: html, css, image-gallery

I need to center align images (variable width and height) inside block level elements of fixed width and height. The css markup looks something like this:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px;"><img src="yada" width="50" height="60"></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px;"><img src="yada" width="60" height="50"></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px;"><img src="yada" width="75" height="75"></div>
```

The point is, that the images align themselves to the top right corners of the container div. I want them to be centered, both horizontally and vertically. I have tried setting the img tag style as follows:

```
img {
display: block;
margin: auto;
}
```

This center-aligns the img horizontally but not vertically. I need both so that the gallery page looks neatly aligned. I need to avoid using tables at all cost although this produces the result exactly as I need. I need a portable, hack-less CSS solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, vertical margins are calculated in a fundamentally different way to horizontal ones; ‘auto’ doesn't mean centering.

Setting ‘vertical-align: middle’ on the image elements sort of works, but it only aligns them relative to the [line box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#line-box) they're currently on. To make the line box the same height as the float, set ‘line-height’ on the container:

```
<style>
    div { float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; line-height: 100px; }
    div img { vertical-align: middle; }
</style>
```

You have to be in [Standards Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) for this to work, because otherwise browsers render images-on-their-own as blocks instead of inline replaced elements in a text line box.

Unfortunately, IE (up to 7 at least) still keeps the block behaviour even in its attempt at a Standards Mode. There is a technical reason for this, namely that IE is pants.

To persuade IE that you really mean it about the images being part of a text line, you have to add some text inside the div — even a normal space will do it, but you could also try a zero-width-space:

```
<div><img src="http://i.stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png" width="50" height="60" />&#8203;</div>
<div><img src="http://i.stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png" width="60" height="50" />&#8203;</div>
<div><img src="http://i.stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png" width="75" height="75" />&#8203;</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work, although firefox reports that the browser is in standards compliance mode. Can you post a url for this example if its working somewhere. I might be able to compare the difference between csses.

Comment: All rignt, adding a non breaking space after the image tag worked! looks kind of ugly though.

Comment: Works for me without the space in Firefox (full) Standards Mode. But yes, a space will be needed anyway for IE. A normal space works for me in IE (but not in Firefox in Quirks Mode). I went for zero-width rather than non-breaking, to avoid any unwanted increase in content size.

Comment: I like your outline of the technical reasons for IE's broken standards mode, sir. Well done! :)