# Image center align vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to place a Image which is center align vertically and horizontally as well,
My HTML markup is

```
<ul class="big-wrapper">
<li>
<div class="filler" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">
    <img src="7-612x612-2.png" original="/7-612x612-2.png" style="margin: 0pt auto; display: table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="filler" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">
    <img src="7-612x612-2.png" original="/7-612x612-2.png" style="margin: 0pt auto; display: table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">

</li>
</ul>

Used Css
ul.big-wrapper li > div {
height:612px;
width:612px;
}

ul.big-wrappe li {
float:left;
margin:0 20px 20px 0;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
}
```

After doing all those stuff i am not able to do so.Please have a look and help me.

Comment: I suggest that you look at a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720495/vertical-align-block-level-element-inside-a-block-level-element).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There's a few good ways to both horizontally and vertically center an element, it just comes down to the situation and your preference.

With the following markup:

```
<div><img src="a.png" width="100" height="100"></div>
```

### line-height

```
div { width:300px; height:300px; line-height:300px; text-align:center; }
div img { vertical-align:middle; }
```

Good quick fix without messing with `position`ing too much but if actually text is being centered this way could be problematic.

### display:table-cell

```
div { width:300px; height:300px; text-align:center; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; }
```

Works just like good old tables and highly flexible, however only supported in modern browsers.

### position:absolute

```
div { width:300px; height:300px; position:relative; }
div img { top:-50px; left:-50px; position:absolute; margin:50% 0 0 50%; }
```

`top` and `left` offsets should be set to half the respective dimensions of the element being positioned. Works well if the containing element needs to be flexible but absolute values are required to work.

---

### Demo of all techniques: [jsfiddle.net/Marcel/JQbea](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/JQbea/) ([fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/JQbea/show/))

Answer (score 17):

why not just remove the `img` tags then set the image as a `background` and center it like this:

(doing it inline, but via external css file is the best way)

```
<div style="background: url('7-612x612-2.png') no-repeat center center transparent;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: no i cant do this due to its my requirement.

Comment: What if you want the image to have a border color?