# Center Image Vertical and Horizontal

Tags: css

I tend to do this every web site I design I do, but I have yet to actually find a real good way to do it. A company usually gives me their logo, I center it in the middle of the screen for when you go to the page, and then it auto forwards you to the home page. I can not seem to find a good way to center an image in the middle of the screen without a bunch of tables and divs! Any good suggestions?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image center align vertically and horizontally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481821/image-center-align-vertically-and-horizontally)

Comment: more ways of vertical centering: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try using a `div` in your HTML like this:

```
<div id='dv'></div>
```

And using a background image like this:

```
#dv {
    background: url('http://pieisgood.org/images/slice.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
    background-position: center;
}

html,body,#dv { /* so that the #dv can fill up the page */
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZngsR)

Comment: If the image is of significant contextual value, a background image is not the best solution.

Comment: but this works even in the oldest browsers, which is more significant to give support for them on a landingpage

Comment: Awesome! How would you be able to resize the image though? Say it's 1000x900 and I only wanted it 400x300? @Doorknob

Comment: @jadeallencook You could use `background-size: 400px 300px;`

Comment: Just ran into another problem. What if I want to center a div the same way that is 400 x idk yet ?

Answer (score 4):

```css
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */     
}
```

```html
<body>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRMtBiLioXqfhufpptex_ta8kGJa5UDQS3aITpBetR8EwH5GGDTJw" />   
</body>
```

Related: [Center a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers/46367524#46367524)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like using the `display: table-cell` method.

For example, if my HTML is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" alt="Company ABC" />
</div>
```

Then my CSS should be:

```
div.wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

If I'm unable to use the above method, another viable option is to use the `line-height` property.

HTML for line-height method:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" alt="Company XYZ" />
</div>
```

CSS for line-height method:

```
img {
    line-height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to calculate the center point and position it with either margin or top (with position:relative/absolute), but this isn't really clean.

I'm assuming you're talking about a splash page, so here is a simple example (although in other circumstances I do not recommend modifying the `body` tag as I have done):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>blah</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html,body {margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;height:100%;}
            body {display:table;}
            p {display:table-cell;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello World - This could have an image in it</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The trick is in the CSS:

- The item you wish to center both horizontally and vertically is displayed as a table cell: `display:table-cell`
- The parent (container) of the item you wish to center is displayed as a table: `display:table`
- Make sure the table display element is consuming the entire area which you would like to center against.
- The item you wish to center must be told to align horizontally (`text-align:center` declaration) and vertically (`vertical-align:middle` declaration)
- The `text-align` and `vertical-align` properties only work this special way because the element is displayed as a `table-cell`

Answer (score 1):

You don't say if the image size is known.

There are a couple of ways to do this, I favour some CSS like so on an image with `id="centreme"` (if the image is 200x200) and a wrapper for the entire page

```
div#contentwrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
img#centreme {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;   /* the image width */
    height: 200px;  /* the image height */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;  /* half the image height */
    margin-left:-100px;  /* half the image width */
}
```

fiddle for you to play with http://jsfiddle.net/7PYzB/2/