# DIV - exact center of page

Tags: html, css

I need to place a div exactly in the middle of the page with an unknown width and height. I can get it centered with the width but is it possible to get it centered with the height?

HTML:

```
<div class='lightbox'>
    <div class='tc-content'>AAA</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.lightbox { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    text-align: center;
}

.tc-content {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481821/image-center-align-vertically-and-horizontally

Answer (score 1):

Use this style for tc-content

```
.tc-content {
    position: relative;
    top: calc(50% - 1em);
}
```

Here is a working **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nozLs2tg/)**

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times I use this to center divs horizontally and vertically

```
.lightbox {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    /* Other code here */   
}
```