# CSS vertical alignment problem

Tags: html, css

Consider the following example: ([live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jESsA/))

HTML:

```
<div id="outer_wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a><img src="http://img.brothersoft.com/icon/softimage/s/smiley.s_challenge-131939.jpeg" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a><img src="http://assets.test.myyearbook.com/pimp_images/home_page/icon_smiley.gif" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a><img src="http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/m/mvHqVR-GDRQ2AzadtgupdgQ/80.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/718smiley.png/60px-718smiley.png" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer_wrapper {
    background-color: #bbb;
    width: 350px;
}
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 90px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The output is:

[image]

1. Why the black `wrapper`s are not vertically aligned ? How could I fix that ?
2. The images are horizontally centered in the red boxes. How could I vertically center them ?

Please do not change the HTML, if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical align block level element inside a block level element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720495/vertical-align-block-level-element-inside-a-block-level-element)???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that it is the base of the images which are aligned. This is to do with the `vertical-align`; if you use a value for `vertical-align` on `.wrapper` other than `baseline`, like `top`, `middle` or `bottom`, it will fix it. (The difference between these will only be apparent if you put some text inside the `div` as well.)

Then you want to centre the images in their 80x80 spots. You can do that with `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` on the `a` (and add `line-height: 0` to fix a couple more issue). You can then play further with mixing these groups of styles in the `a` tag, the `.wrapper`, or even throwing away the `.wrapper` if it isn't necessary (it would only be needed - if it is at all - if you're putting text in with it).

Result, with no further tweaks than what I've mentioned here: http://jsfiddle.net/jESsA/38/.

This will work on all decent browsers, and even on IE8/9, but it won't work on IE6/7. A technique for solving this which should work in IE6/7 is this: on the `a`, set `display` to `block` and alter the `line-height` from `0` to `78px` (I'm not entirely clear on why `80px` makes it shift down one pixel, but it does; if I thought about it long enough I could probably figure out why), and shift the `vertical-align: middle` to the `img` child. Final result: http://jsfiddle.net/jESsA/44/

Comment: Note on browser compatibility: CSS table display isn't supported in IE6 or IE7 ([#](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)).

Comment: Thanks for the first part! Regarding the second part: I really need it work in IE7 :) Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try assigning a `vertical-align` attribute on the `img` tag. Vertical align is relative to the line box which means you need to set the line box as tall as the height of the `a` tag. So these changes are needed in your CSS markup:

```
#outer_wrapper {
    overflow: hidden; /* required when you float everything inside it */
}

.wrapper {
    /* display: inline-block is not required */
    /* text-align: center is not required -- see below */
    float: left; /* float all wrappers left */
}

a {
    display: block; /* block display required to make width and height behave as expected */
    margin-left: 4px; /* shift the block to make it horizontally centered */
    margin-top: 9px; /* shift the block to make it vertically centered */
    text-align: center; /* center inline content horizontally */
    line-height: 80px; /* line height must be set for next item to work */
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle; /* presto */
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/xMV4R/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jESsA/37/

Basically you use `float: left` to put your boxes inline and a **background image** instead of an *img* tag. Because you are using *float*, you need to **clear** after to cancel the float effect on other elements.

I changed the DIV tags to A tags so you can have a link on the hole block and keep it simple. But you can keep it as a DIV tag and put an A block inside though (or use JavaScript)

Comment: "Please do not change the HTML, if possible." - How can we be sure the images are merely decoration and not content? Switching to backgrounds may not be appropriate.

Comment: "If possible". I agree that switching to backgrounds may not be appropriate. But I wanted to show him an example, now he can decide if it's appropriate or not.

Comment: Although this does not meet OP's requirements it is a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
  float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jESsA/3/

Answer (score 0):

You could check this out: http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help you

http://css.flepstudio.org/en/css-tutorials/centered-vertical-horizontal-align.html

it helped me :)