# Centering/Vertically aligning images within <div> tags

Tags: html, css, image

I have noticed that when using both `line-height` and `text-align` attributes to center and vertically align an image inside of a `<div>` tag, for some reason the image is pushed down by a couple of pixels. This change is hardly noticable if your image has plenty of whitespace surrounding it, however when i have a `150px` by `150px` image within a `150px` by `150px` sized box, you can see where the image has been pushed out slightly. Does anybody know why this does this?

http://jsfiddle.net/rUs5E/

Comment: some code or a jsfiddle would be helpful

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS vertical alignment problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742686/css-vertical-alignment-problem)

Comment: could you perhaps provide a sample where this happens on for instance  http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: @Diodeus no it isn't a duplicate, i'm asking a question for my own issue..

Comment: Do you have any working fiddle? please give a link here.

Comment: No i don't because i can't find an image to create an example with.. But the problem i'm having is when you apply both vertical-align: middle; and text-align: center; to `.testDiv img { }` it decides to bounce the image down by around 3/4 pixels pushing it out of the box it should perfectly fit into.

Comment: @LeeB try placing the `vertical-align: middle` in the `.testDiv img { }` and the `text-align: center;` in `.testDiv {}`.

Comment: This is currently how i'm doing it, i appreciate the advice, however i have edited my post to include the jsfiddle i have created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `vertical-align:middle` is a bit odd. [It says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)

> "Align the vertical midpoint of the box with the baseline of the parent box plus half the x-height of the parent."

The shift you are seeing is the effect of a combination of "half the x-height of the parent." and a shift of the baseline, both based on the font-size. You can therefore eliminate it by setting the font-size of the parent (in your jsfiddle `.searchLogo`) to zero. This makes the x-height = 0 and the baseline run through the centre line of the box and there is no shift.

See http://jsfiddle.net/rUs5E/1/

Comment: You sir, are a genius. One question, what about alt tags? Would they become affected?

Comment: Scrap the last question, your solution allowed me to find a fix. I've got the logo stored in a box, so i've set the `<div>` tags CSS attributes to `font-size: 0;` and `line-height: 150px;` then i've done `.div img {}` and put `font: 12px Arial;` and `vertical-align: middle;`, this has now solved the problem of no alt tags and the alignment issue. If anyone can find a way to use this answer as an answer to all questions of alignment issues it's to wrap your image within a `div` and set the attributes to the image of that tag.

Answer (score 2):

[Possibly a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844205/html-5-strange-img-always-adds-3px-margin-at-bottom) but:

You can add a `vertical-align: middle`.
This has to do with the image being treated as a character. I think default is `vertical-align: baseline` which seems to add soemthing like 3px to the bottom.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tRDrm/)

Comment: That's not really the issue i'm having. If i could find a picture to use i would provide an example but using links as src's isn't working for some odd reason

Comment: Ok, I see. Try to get a fiddle going and I'll try to get a better answer!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rUs5E/ there we are, kinda displays the problem, as you can see the problem is noticed on the flag, however on the full sized images you can see the issue is noticable.

Comment: i will try it, but may i just ask why the `line-height` attribute is causing it to bounce down?