# Placing an image in the center of <a> tag

Tags: image, css, hyperlink, centering

There is a tag in 150x130:

```
.listings ul li a.thumb{
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    height:130px;
    border:#ededed 3px solid;
}
```

When I save an image I check the image's width and height. with==150 or height==130. And in view:

```
    <a href="#" class="thumb">
      if ( checking with is full )
      {
         <img src="@Url.Content( Path.Combine( "~/Uploads/Products/", @item.ImagePath ) )" style = "width: 150px;" alt="" />
      }
  if ( checking height is full )
      {
         <img src="@Url.Content( Path.Combine( "~/Uploads/Products/", @item.ImagePath ) )" style = "height: 130px;" alt="" />
      }
    </a>
```

There are images in this `<a>` tag in different sizes. For example, 100x130, 70x130, 150x140, 150x80 etc. But one of sizes of image equals to one of sizes of a tag. (150 or 130). Square images are not a problem, but different sized images seem to go in bottom or top, right or left side in the `<a>` tag.

How can place all size images **center** of the tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720495/vertical-align-block-level-element-inside-a-block-level-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to convert the `<a>` to a block element with `display:block`.

Second, I would set your thumbnail as a background image instead and use `background-position: center center` which would cente rit vertically and horizontally

```
<a href="#" class="thumb" 
  style="background-image: url('@Url.Content( Path.Combine( "~/Uploads/Products/", @item.ImagePath ) )')">&nbsp;</a>
```

Comment: `background-repeat: no-repeat` too

Comment: that is required too. Good catch

Comment: This works, as I want. but..image zooms in much. not seems full, seems only center of image.

Comment: This should be 'zooming' the images at all. If you want to increase the image to fill the <a>, then you can use the CSS3 property background-size: 150px 130px;

Answer (score 2):

Maybe add `display: block;` to both `a` and `img` and then add `margin: 0px auto;` to your `img`.

Answer (score 1):

There are differences between HTML 4.01 and HTML5 in the  tag.
The layout attributes: align, border, hspace, and vspace were **deprecated** in HTML 4.01, and are not supported in HTML5!
You have to wrap your  tag in an other one and make your CSS do the align like this exemple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <article style="text-align:center">
    <img src="img/test.png" alt="test" />
  </article>
</body>
</html>
```